# Android webview issue whilst playing cached video (Codec?)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, rendering, codec

We are trying to play a video in android WebView, but are unable to play it.
In the logcat we find warnings and errors about missing or unsupported mime profiles/codecs.
The video stutters every once in a while (3 seconds of play time, 2 seconds pause)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.twodisplaywebview);
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.cacheMode = LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK;

        webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)

        webView.loadUrl("linktowebpagewithvideo");

    }
}
```

We have tried video's with different codec's but most of them dont even play.
We have used different caching modes.
We have tried software and hardware rendering.
In the webpage we have used the video element and the HTML5 video element, both have the same issue.

We are targeting to a webpage that wil be playing different video's (playlist) which will be hosted on a webserver.
We have source control over the android app and the loaded webpage.